# How to find the followers that follow two same pages Instagram

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, list, instagram

I got threatened by one guy and he threatened my girlfriend from his fake account, we want to know who he is because he still follows her. And all I know that he follow her and one more guy with 1 thousand followers. I was thinking of copying HTML of all my girlfriend's followers and copy all that 1 thousand follower guys followers and compare them if there is someone who follow both my girlfriend and that 1 thousand follower guy I will know who is that guy. I don't know how to do it I started programming a few weeks ago I'm really bad but improving.. If you would help me how to do it I would be very grateful for it. I don't want this guy on his main account to stalk my girlfriend... <3

Comment: I appreciate the interesting story behind your question!
To add something related to your question: I know that HTML of "production" webpages sometimes looks horrible, but if this isn't your example, your way should be okay (getting rid of tags should be possible with only little effort). Which social network are you talking about?

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: @TomášChabada It's Instagram. Sorry that I didn't mention it.

Comment: I inspected it and I am not very big optimist. It SHOULD be possible, but it would take a lot of effort to write any sensible code. The nickname is hidden five or so levels deep in `<li>` tag. I think `Ctrl+F` for each of your girlfriend's follower (if she has 100 followers or so) will be faster.
You can inspect it too - on Firefox you just rightclick the follower's name and click Inspect element. You'll see the mess on your own.

Comment: @TomášChabada I did inspect it and after href=" there is a nickname of each user " i copied that part where is the list of these usernames, sadly my girlfriend has 3000 followers, is there any way I can get rid of everything besides whats inside of href quotation mark in the text?

Comment: If there are no further hrefs then yes, it should be possible quite easily. I cannot parse strings etc., so if there are no other hrefs in the structure, I would just seach for "href", the I'd move two chars forward (to the `"` mark) and load the string till next `"`. If there are more of hrefs, it is going to be harder, though some people might help. In any case, I recommend you to ask new, more specific question ^^ (about getting of the string username from the structure - if you decide to do so, post the structure there so other people may refer to it).

Comment: @TomášChabada In 1 thousand follow guy html code there is about 1000 hrefs and 3000 hrefs in my girlfriends html. I want to copy them all out and compare but I dont know how, there is alot of other code that I dont need and want to delete I try using replacing tool but still failure..

Comment: As I suggest, ask a new question about getting the username. I cannot help you with that.

Comment: You could use a bot that parses the Instagram accounts needed. I don't know what languages you code with, but you should try Python: [How to Make an Instagram Bot With Python and InstaPy](https://realpython.com/instagram-bot-python-instapy/)